# Master Node on AKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, azure-container-service

I created a Kubernetes cluster using AKS service.

When I execute `kubectl get nodes`, I expect to see the Master node. However, I don't. I only see the Agent (Role) nodes.

Is it possible to look at the Master node? The reason I want to do this is to check if RBAC is enabled in my cluster, and if not, enable it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to look at Master node? The reason I want to do this is
>   to check if RBAC is enabled in my cluster, and if not, enable it.

It is **not** possible, Kubernetes master node managed by Azure, because Azure handles these critical maintenance tasks for you, AKS does **not** provide direct access (such as with SSH) to the cluster.

If you need more control over the Azure resource manager templates, you can use the open source [acs-engine](https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine) project to build your own custom kubernetes cluster and deploy it via the az CLI.

Comment: **not** possible with GKE also

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command using azure CLI to verify if the clsuter has RBAC enabled or not

```
az resource show -g <resource-group-name> -n <aks-cluster-name> --resource-type Microsoft.ContainerService/ManagedClusters --query properties.enableRBAC
```