# Is it possible to include a custom node (Raspi Pi) to a Managed AKS?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have an Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster and need to join my Raspberry Pi (Will be something else in future) into that cluster as a worker node.
I also have a VPN established into that cluster and I am able to ping the existing cluster node.

However, I am stuck at the kubeadm join command because of beeing Unauthorized:

```sh
sudo kubeadm join [...] --token [...] --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:[...] --v=11

[...]
I0419 12:58:23.359475    7173 round_trippers.go:425] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.20.5 (linux/arm) kubernetes/6b1d87a" '[...]/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s'
I0419 12:58:23.489180    7173 round_trippers.go:445] GET [...]/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s 401 Unauthorized in 129 milliseconds
I0419 12:58:23.489385    7173 round_trippers.go:451] Response Headers:
I0419 12:58:23.489479    7173 round_trippers.go:454] Audit-Id: 2a61af8a-4253-4e8d-b5d7-3eade3dbabcd
I0419 12:58:23.489595    7173 round_trippers.go:454] Cache-Control: no-cache, private
I0419 12:58:23.489684    7173 round_trippers.go:454] Content-Type: application/json
I0419 12:58:23.489771    7173 round_trippers.go:454] Content-Length: 129
I0419 12:58:23.489985    7173 round_trippers.go:454] Date: Mon, 19 Apr 2021 12:58:23 GMT
I0419 12:58:23.490679    7173 request.go:1107] Response Body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}
I0419 12:58:23.494752    7173 token.go:215] [discovery] Failed to request cluster-info, will try again: Unauthorized
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54934255/unable-to-join-new-node-to-existing-cluster-discovery-failed-to-request-clust) article has pointed out that I have to set the "--anonymous-auth"-flag correctly in the Kubernetes Config on the Master Node, but it is [not possible to access a Master node of AKS via ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143225/master-node-on-aks-cluster).

Therefore, I am questioning now if it is even possible to join custom nodes to an AKS cluster or if I have to set up a self-managed Kubernetes Cluster.

Im fairly new to this topic, so if I can supply any more information, please let me know.